# Java, read in text file, printing new file with removing some columns and using operations in columns?

Tags: java, file-io

I have to read in a text file that has multiple columns, the 1st column being state number (01-50), the 2nd column being a name of a certain housing location, the 3rd column has the total population per town that the housing location is in, the 4th column is the number of possible housing capacity, the 5th column has the number of available housing from the previous column. The 6th and 7th columns have useless ID numbers and dates. Each state has multiple housing locations.

The goal is to create a new output, with 1 row for each state. The 1st column has to be the state number, 2nd has to be total population per state given each town population, the 3rd column has to be total number of possible housing capacity, the 4th column has to be the total availability, and the 5th column has to be the percentage of availability. I have to get rid of the columns that I do not need.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class housing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "housingdata.txt";
        try {
            FileReader File = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(File);
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] splittedLine = line.split("\\s+");
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception) {
       System.out.println("Error.");
    }
}
```

**Sample Data:**

```
01 Grainey County Housing Complex     2000     500      340 ID: 45440  March2010   
02 MainStays Housing Complex          3465     400       82 ID: 30094  March2010
```

Comment: If you have code in your question, make sure you add a tag for the language.

Comment: Could you provide a small bit of sample data for inspection?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If Java 8, this would be a nice example of using the `Stream` API

Comment: Also, what exactly isn't working, what have you tried, how did it fail (error? stack trace?)  Either I missed it or I don't see a specific question but a broad end result.'

Comment: @QuinnRoundy I dont know how to remove the columns that I don't need, and don't know how to do column operations, like adding a certain number data per state.

Comment: @rmuller Java 8 i believe.

Comment: It sounds like, to me, you have a scenario like this: Read data, process data, produce new data based on processing of data, Write new data. If I'm right then you are 'removing' them, you're just not writing them. But maybe I'm not reading this right?

Comment: Is it like a data base normalization ?

Comment: @QuinnRoundy Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @joeyrohan I am unsure what that is, I am a novice.

Comment: Data Base normalization is a process where we try to move multivalued columns to new table.Anyway can you update `housingdata.txt`

Comment: sounds like you need to decide what collection to use first, the deal with reading into collection

Comment: I built a simple regex to capture the data from a single line. Then you would just need to put that into some data structure that you could run over and check in order to produce your result data. Heres the Regex : "(\d{2})\s+([^\d]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+ID:\s+(\d+)\s+([\w\d]+)"

Comment: @joeyrohan housingdata.txt looks just like the sample data above, but with many different lines per state.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working on list of tasks. First read and store data (to be able to process it)

For this you would probably want to build a data structure, and then pick a collection for it. ArrayList should probably generically work (no pun intended)

```
class Data
{
    private int stateID;
    private String name;
    private int totalPopulation;
    private int totalAvailable;
    private int hereAvailable;

    // Appropriate setters/getters and constructor
    public Data(int stateID, String name, int population, int availablePop, int availHere, int ID, String date) { ... }
}
```

I would created a ArrayList inherited class to levi the functionality of ArrayList while allowing to add specific functionality.

```
class DataList extends ArrayList<Data>
{
    public addData(Data data) { this.add(data); }
}
```

Then you just collect the data. I wrote it something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Housing {

    static String fileName = "housingdata.txt";
    static DataList data = new DataList();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line;

        try(FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName))
        {
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(file);
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\d{2})\s+([^\d]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+ID:\s+(\d+)\s+([\w\d]+)");

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

                data.addData(
                        new Data(
                                Integer.parseInt(m.group(0)),
                                m.group(1),
                                Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)),
                                Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)),
                                Integer.parseInt(m.group(4)),
                                Integer.parseInt(m.group(5)),
                                m.group(6)
                        )
                );
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After this you just need to figure out how to calculate the data you need to produce your output. I think I would suggest using a hashset as some point. In fact I suppose if you built your own custom hashlist you could easily use it to just return the calculations. There are many other ways this could be done, this is just how I quickly put it together thus far.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm unable to use Arraylist and any regex, as we didnt cover either yet. Is there an alternative?

Comment: If you haven't covered ArrayList then I doubt you've covered hashlists either, and I doubt you're equipped to make your own datatypes. If you know how much data you have then you could use multidimensional array (everything would have to be strings though, so doing math would require converting to int when necessary) If you really wanted to avoid that you would have to create variable to store final data, then as you read data do the math then. A bit more code for that.

Comment: I know how much data is in the original text file, yes, and I would be able to use multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: any chance I could see what the array would look like? Just sort of confused still.

Comment: I'm guessing you're probably supposed to use 1 variable per stat for collecting the stats as you read your data in.

Comment: That sounds about right, but i don't believe there is any restriction on the amount of variables.